# OpenID connect Project error: Error in handling response type

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, azure, ssl

I am using azure active directory for authentication and it was working fine few days before. Now I get error like openid connect provider error. I didnt change any code in my application.
I am using aws beanstalk for hosting my application. A few days before I was redeploy my application.
Is this any aws configration issue or ssl certificate issue?

Could you please help me to solve this?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ?